# Find largest $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a \times b \geq n$

Tags: divisibility, discrete-geometry

I have the following problem: I have $n$ images that I want to display on-screen. $n$ might be any number from $\mathbb{N}$. If I have one Image, I want this layout (* is an image, _ is empty space):

```
*
```

If I have two images, I want to have it like this:

```
**
```

For three images, I want

```
**
*_
```

For four images, I want

```
**
**
```

and so on. So, for aligning this, I need a function that returns two values, the height and the width (1 = one image).

Let's say I have this function, it's output should look like this:

$ f(n) = (x, y)$

$ f(1) = (1, 1)$

$ f(2) = (1, 2)$

$ f(3) = f(4) = (2, 2)$

$ f(5) = f(6) = (3, 2) $

$ f(7) = f(8) = (2, 4) $

$ f(9) = (3, 3) $

$ f(10) = (5, 2) $

$ f(11) = f(12) = (4, 3) $

The $x$-$y$-order does not really matter that much here.

My problem here is that I don't know how to non-statically write such a function. Stating it for, like, the first 100 numbers isn't gonna cut it, because n might be very large here.

As far as I see, for non-prime-numbers I get the two largest divisors and for prime numbers, I add some $n$ up to the point where it isn't a prime number anymore and then go to step one (the largest divisors).

But is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: "for non-prime-numbers I get the two largest divisors" I doubt you want $6\times 9$ for $n = 18$. What I think you want are the two divisors closest to $\sqrt n$, on either side. That will give you the "squariest" rectangle possible of area $n$. However, you also accept empty spots, meaning you need to come up with some strict definition of how you weigh "squariness" against filling all the spots. _Why_ would you rather have $2\times 2$ than $3\times 1$ for $n = 3$? Is $2\times 4$ really better than $3\times 3$ for $n = 8$? What about $n = 7$?

Comment: Yes, that's a very good objection and very true.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't really describe what you want in general. For example, why not use the $3x3$ layout for $n=7,8$ (leaving 1/2 open places)? 
For a layout problem, usually the space is limited, so you might want to find a configuration that makes each picture as big as possible, but of course scrolling can create unbounded space.

Comment: In short, you have a lot of thinking to do before you can actually ask a question. You have to decide, and be able to communicate, exactly what it is that you want. Take some time to figure that out.

Comment: One option could be to trying to minimize $u(a,b)=ab-n+|a-b|$ to get a 'square-like' appearance with little unused space.